# How can I decouple configuration data from the program that uses it?

Tags: design-patterns

I am a beginning programmer who has written a spider application in PHP. Currently there are three parts:

```
1) The Spider (spider.php)
2) The Harvester (harvest.php)
3) The Configuration file (for example, craigslist_config.php)
```

I use the spider to search the web for items I want to buy. An item can be found on any website, like ebay, craigslist, etc. The Harvester provides three functions to spider so it can act on the data it finds - `get_title_from($markup)`, `get_description_from($markup)`, and `get_price_from($markup)`.

Each web site that I want to spider has, of course, different markup surrounding the data that I want to extract. My config file contains a configuration array that holds the regex patterns for each of the items I want to find. The structure of the file is always the same, the only thing that changes is the regex patterns. So, I would have craigslist_config.php, ebay_config.php, etc.

```
$conf = array(
    'title' => ' specific_site title pattern',
    'description => 'specific_site description pattern',
    'price' => 'specific_site price pattern'
);
```

My problem is when I want to add a new website.  I have to edit the Spider.php file and add to an ever-growing "if, elseif" statement that detects what site is currently being read, and load the correct config file, which in turn feeds the correct REGEX data to the harvester functions.

How can I decouple my configuration from my Spider.php file? What I have designed does not feel like a flexible, scalable solution, and I don't want to have to mess with spider.php everytime I want to add or take away a new site.

Ultimately, what I am trying to achieve is the ability to simply drop in a new configuration file into my config directory and move the 'if, elseif' logic somewhere else so that the spider and harverster functions never have to worry about what files are or are not included in the config directory. It's the "somewhere else" I am having trouble figuring out. Actually, it would be even better if I could get rid of the 'if else' logic all together so that everything just 'works.'

My current design is not an OOP approach, however I am not opposed to one. I am currently reading, "PHP Objects, Patterns, and Practice" to get up to speed on OOP and related design patterns, so feel free to suggest in that direction should you feel it a solution.

**EDIT:** Based on Doc Brown's direction, I have come up with the following. I have individual configuration files with content like so:

```
$conf['specificwebsite1.com'] = array(
    'title' => 'title pattern',
    'price' => 'price pattern',

    etc...
);
```

In my Harvester file I have a new function called `load_config($url, $config)`. As suggested, I loops through all the configuration files and load them into one large $conf array. Then, the `load_config` function checks if the key is a sub string of the url I'm currently reading. If so, then it loads all the necessary values to continue parsing.  This is the function:

```
function load_config($url, $config){
  foreach($config as $key => $value){
    if(stristr($url, $key) !== FALSE){
      ## see if a key in our config file
      ## is a substring of our url. 
      $conf = $config[$key];
      break;
    } else {

      $conf = FALSE;
    }
  }

  return $conf;
}
```

This is working really well, so I'll accept that as the answer. But please feel free to make suggestions for improvements in the comments or as another answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ultimately, what I am trying to achieve is the ability to simply drop in a new configuration file into my config directory

First, add the related web address to your config file:

```
$conf = array(
    'url' => ' specific_site url or url pattern',
    'title' => ' specific_site title pattern',
    'description => 'specific_site description pattern',
    'price' => 'specific_site price pattern'
);
```

Now, change the code in your Spider.php that it checks all .php files in that config directory,  loads them all dynamically one-by-one, and store the "$conf" content in a dictionary where the url is used as a key. Then it should be easy to replace your "if-else" list by a simple loop over that dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Keep the configuration files as simple as possible. That means: avoid PHP code and redundancy (like XML). A suitable format is the INI format, which can be read by PHP into an array.

```
[specificwebsite1.com]
title="title pattern"
price="price pattern"

[anotherwebsite.com]
title="title pattern"
price="price pattern"
```

With that, your configuration files are human readable and easy to maintain, and you can put several configurations into one file.

The next step is to create a directory for these files, lets call it `config`. Store the configuration files in that directory, naming them in a way that makes it easy for you to find a specific one.

Now, you can read the configurations from PHP:

```
$configs = array();
foreach (glob('config/*.ini') as $filename) {
    $configs = array_merge($configs, parse_ini_file($filename, true));
}
```

`$configs` now contains all your configurations, indexed by site name.

Comment: Nice to learn about the ini style capability. I had not used parse_ini_file before.  Looking at the PHP.net docs, it looks like I can created multidimensional arrays as well? This seems to be a lot cleaner than the $conf array I created and just as flexible. Thanks for the direction!

Comment: Yes, of course arrays can have several dimensions ;-)

Comment: As long as you (the developer of the program) are the only one adding new configurations, it does not make a real difference if you use some kind of ini files or a php file for configs (using the script language itself for configs is an old trick I have seen in "The Perl cookbook" >10 years ago). If, however, this task is going to be shifted to a user of your program, I would definitely agree that using ini files is better suited.